# Are the algebraic-valued points of a variety dense in complex-valued points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety (integral scheme of finite type) over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$. We may endow the sets $X(\overline{\mathbb Q})$ and $X(\mathbb C)$ of  $\overline{\mathbb Q}$- resp. $\mathbb C$-valued points of $X$ with the topologies induced by the topology on $\overline{\mathbb Q} \subset \mathbb C$. We have $X(\overline{\mathbb Q}) \subset X(\mathbb C)$.

*Q:* Is $X(\overline{\mathbb Q})$ dense in  $X(\mathbb C)$?

For a smooth $X$ I can show this. For $\dim X = 0$ this is also true.

*Ansatz*:
The question is local on $X$, so we can assume that $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$, $A = \overline{\mathbb Q}[X_1, \ldots, X_n]/(f_1, \ldots, f_r)$ for polynomials $f_i$ in variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$. So the question is, whether
$$
\{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \overline{\mathbb Q}^n~|~f_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0~\text{for all}~i \}
$$
is dense in
$$
\{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb C^n~|~f_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0~\text{for all}~i \}.
$$

Comment: I take it that by that bar over the Q you mean to denote the algebraic numbers. So, you are not actually asking about rational-valued points, but algebraic-valued points. If I have that right, maybe you would want to edit the title of the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Done, thank you.

Comment: How do you prove the result in the smooth case?

Comment: @finite: want a direct proof without reducing to the smooth case ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: By considering étale neighborhoods from $\mathbb A^n_{\overline{\mathbb Q}}$ which are local isomorphisms on $\mathbb C$-valued points by implicit function theorem. They give charts to open sets in $\mathbb C^n$. Further, I approximate a point by points in this charts with coordinates in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$. This is independent of the chosen chart, since the change to a different chart is given by a $\overline{\mathbb Q}$-morphism.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @finite.

Comment: @Cantlog: although you are not asking me, I certainly would love to see a direct proof !

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg Georges, I thought I had a simple proof, but it is essentially the same as that of "finite": consider a Noether normalization map $X\to \mathbb A^n_{\overline{\mathbb Q}}$, remove the nonwhere Zariski (hence complex) dense ramification locus and we are reduced to the \'etale situation.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg  The answer of Pete Clark to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178461/complex-variety-with-zariski-dense-set-of-algebraic-points might be useful here. It seems that he has a direct proof (which I do not understand) of density of algebraic points, which does not involve generic regularity.

Comment: Also, Martin Brandenburg seems to know an easy proof of generic regularity (see his comment here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435510/generic-regularity-of-affine-varieties) which I do not understand at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The smooth locus of $X(\mathbb C)$ is Zarisk dense, hence [dense for the complex topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366966/), in $X(\mathbb C)$. So it is enough to prove the density for smooth varieties, and you already known how to do it.

Comment: Dear @Cantlog, the smooth locus $X^{sm} \subset X$ is Zariski-dense, but why it is also dense in the complex topology? The latter topology is much finer as the Zariski-topology.

Comment: @finite: good question ! See edit.

Comment: @finite: see also Mumford, "Complex Projective Varieties", Theorem 2.33, p.38.

Comment: By the way, this is  not the best book he wrote, compared to the great "Red book" and "Abelian varieties".